# Is どんなことでも失敗したら a whole clause or two separate clauses?

Tags: parsing, subordinate-clauses, clause-pattern, ambiguous-relative-clauses

Is the sentence どんなことでも失敗したら、人のせいにしてはなりません。read as:

1. [どんなことでも][失敗したら]、人のせいにしてはなりません。
   = [No matter what][if you fail], don't blame people.
   or
2. [どんなことでも失敗したら]、人のせいにしてはなりません。
   = [No matter how you fail], don't blame people.
   ?

---

---

Providing the reason with the answer please.

Answer (score 2):

I would parse it as:

[どんなことでも][失敗したら、人のせいにしてはなりません]。

[No matter what it is,] [if you fail, don't blame others].

<sub>The [人]{ひと} here means [他人]{たにん/ひと}, "others".</sub>

Comment: Could you give me the reason for your choice?

Comment: @raruna cos どんなことでも人のせいにするな makes sense but どんなことでも失敗する doesn't sound natural (it sounds like "you fail in everything you do").

Comment: Grammatically speaking, are both parsings correct?

Comment: @raruna By "both parsing", do you mean 「どんなことでも人のせいにする」 and 「どんなことでも失敗する」? Here in your sentence it's not correct to parse it as どんなことでも失敗する.

Comment: mhm that's what I was asking about.
So the reason for the second parsing being incorrect is that it IS ungrammatical regardless of what you mentioned about it not sounding natural in the context. And that's why I was asking: *Why did you choose your choice?* maybe it's just a rule without a clear reason?